Conditionally Append Cells from a Dynamic Sheet to a Static Sheet Avoiding Duplicates VBA
I have one sheet which is automatically populating from a data set, which is dynamically updating. The problem is, the owner of each of sites can change anytime, and due to this I want to create a static sheet when if the owner changes to lets say Sam in this case, I can just press a button and append the project onto the new sheet.
Example Data:



Project
Owner (Cell E in code)




A
Sam


B
Leah


C
Tom


D
Tom


E
Sam


F
Sam


G
Sam



Desired (All Owned by Sam):



Site




A


E


F


G



I need some code that will search through the data set to see what project is owned by Sam, then append it to the new worksheet. However, it needs to be conditional as to whether it is appended depending if it already has been previously. I also want it to only bring in the project cells and not the full rows because I have various columns which require manual data entry and if the sheet was dynamic and an older project change owners, these manual entries may end up aligning with the wrong projects.
I have been playing around with the below that i found on another thread, but struggling to get it to work.
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ws1LR As Long, ws2LR As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim ws1rng As Range, ws2rng As Range
    Dim ID, ws2sr, Project
    
    'Set the search ID (Sam)
    Set ID = Range("P2")
    
    'Set project sheet range
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Project")
    ws1LR = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set ws1rng = ws1.Range("A1:A" & ws1LR)
    
    'Set data set range
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Data")
    ws2LR = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set ws2rng = ws1.Range("A1:A" & ws2LR)
    
    'loop through data set to find projects with Sam as owner
    For i = 1 To ws2LR
        'Search if cell contains Sam as owner in data
        ws2sr = ws2.Range("E" & i)
        If ws2sr = ID Then
            'call project value
            Project = ws2.Range("E" & i).Offset(0, -3)

            'If project is already in the new worksheet
                'Append project to new sheet
                'Range("A" & ws1rng + 1) = Project
            'Else
                       
        Else
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Example workbook can be found below of what I am trying to achieve.
Download

I'm just trying to follow along her. so first table is a list of sites and owner currently. This can update so the first row may change to "Tom" but then this manual entry sheet is still pointing to Sam? I'm not quite understanding the connection between these two. It may hep to have a bit more clarification and dumb example of how you expect things to flow back and forth. Right now, I struggle to really get the full ask.

Adding a download link for a workbook with mock data would help.   You should also add a worksheet with the expected result.  Considering the columns may not match, I do not see how you are going to get this to make sense to the end users.  I would think that you would also need to match the columns.  Are the column headers consistently name but possibly in a different order?

@MarkS. Let me try explain it a bit better. I have the dynamic sheet which pulls in information of the project and the owner from elsewhere. I essentially want to copy all of the project names into the new sheet, that only belong to Sam in this case. If the third row changed to Sam for example I would need to append that project to the next row in the new sheet, in order to not reorder all of the rows like using the filter function. Additionally, if a new row is added into the dynamic sheet, I need it to append that project onto the new sheet.

This sounds very similar to the original explanation, My confusion is that the first table refreshes and now the third row is changed and no 'history'. But I suppose if you're logging the data into the second sheet you can lookup in the owner back in and see if it matches to determine if you need to append the other table, iterating through the column where the check takes place and if no match, then bring row over. From there i'm back to kind of lost as to what you want to populate the cells with.

@MarkS. did you go onto the workbook? I think that shows it better. Yeah it refreshes which is why I need the code to look up the site, determine if it’s already in the new sheet or not and if it’s not append it.

See if you can lookup in the project owner onto the original table and check if it matches. If it doesn't use a label your VBA can pick up so it knows to move it to the other sheet and do whatever you need. Not downloading any files.

The confusing part is that your code is concatenating the values in the source row cells with values in the destination row cells but you post seems to indicate that you only want the new Project IDs appended to Sam's worksheet.

The mock workbook's data tab should be compatible with the code.    We should be able to run your code sample.

@TinMan yes I didn’t get as far as the part which is concatenating as to change it from the original code. It seems to stop on the scroll part. I can’t seem to get it to work

Please specify exactly what you want the final result to be in your post.   You should probably watch: Excel VBA Dictionary first and continue trying to figure it out.  Happy Coding!!

@MarkS. I think the code I have rewrote may help understand a bit better

I have done it finally, here is the result:
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws1LR As Long, ws2LR As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim ws1rng As Range, ws2rng As Range
Dim ID, ws2sr, Project, Appendcell

'Set the search ID (Sam)
Set ID = Range("P2")

'Set project sheet range
Set ws1 = Sheets("Project")


'Set data set range
Set ws2 = Sheets("Data")
ws2LR = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set ws2rng = ws1.Range("A1:A" & ws2LR)

'loop through data set to find projects with Sam as owner
For i = 1 To ws2LR
    'Search if cell contains Sam as owner in data
    ws2sr = ws2.Range("E" & i)
    
    
    ws1LR = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Appendcell = ws1.Range("A" & ws1LR)
    Set ws1rng = ws1.Range("A1:A" & ws1LR)
    
    If ws2sr = ID Then
        'call project value
        Project = ws2.Range("E" & i).Offset(0, -3)

        'If project is already in the new worksheet
            'Append project to new sheet
        If Trim(Project) <> "" Then
            With ws1.Range("A:A") 'searches all of column A
                Set Rng = .Find(What:=Project, _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
                If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Else
                    'Append to latest row
                     ws1.Range("A" & ws1LR + 1) = Project
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Else
    End If
Next i
End Sub


We can use worksheet formulas to get any missing Project Ids like this:
Sub AppendNewProjectIds()
    Dim OwnerID As String
    OwnerID = Range("P2")
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = Application.Evaluate("=FILTER(Data!A:A, (Data!E:E = """ & OwnerID & """) * ISNA(MATCH(Data!A:A, Project!A:A, 0)))")
    
    With Worksheets("Project")
        If IsArray(Data) Then
            .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(Data)).Value = Data
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Normally, I would use Dictionaries for ID matching.  Here a used a Collection to hold the Project ID and Match to check if they existed already.  I though that this code would be easier for the OP to modify.
Sub AppendNewProjectIds2()
    Dim Col As Collection
    Dim OwnerID As String
    OwnerID = Range("P2").Value
    
    Rem Get a Collection of Project IDs belonging to the Owner
    Set Col = GetOwnerProjects(OwnerID)
    
    Rem Exit the subroutine if there are no projects found for the owner
    If Col.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim Item As Variant ' Declare a variable to iterate through the collection

    With Worksheets("Project")
        ' Loop through each project in the collection
        For Each Item In Col
            Rem Check if the project ID already exists in the "Project" sheet's column A
            Rem Application.Match is used because it does not throw a runtime error if the item is not found.
            Rem Application.Match return Error 2042 (#N/A) if it fails
            Rem Application.IsError is used to test for any errors
            If Application.IsError(Application.Match(Item, .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1), 0)) Then
                Rem If the project ID is not found, append it to the next available row in column A
                .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Item
            End If
        Next Item
    End With
End Sub


Rem Return a Project IDs belonging to the Owner
Function GetOwnerProjects(OwnerID As String) As Collection
    Dim Col As New Collection
    Dim Values As Variant
    
    Rem Range.CurrentRegion property
    Rem  The current region is a range bounded by any combination of blank rows and blank columns.
    Rem .Resize(, 5) ensures that the range has 5 columns
    
    With Worksheets("Data")
        Rem Loading the Range.Value into arrays is preferred for performance
        Values = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 5).Value
    End With
    
    Dim r As Long
    
    Rem UBound(Values) returns upper bounds of the array (row count is our case)
    For r = 2 To UBound(Values)
        Rem If the owner in column 5 matches the OwnerID, add the project ID from column 1 to the collection
        If Values(r, 5) = OwnerID Then Col.Add Values(r, 1)
    Next r

    Set GetOwnerProjects = Col
End Function

